reinforcement learning reward choices
To start with, this is not a homework thing. In my attempt to finally get a practical working knowledge of table based re-inforcement learning, I came up with a very silly and easy dice game, serving as an example. But early on, I ran into problems, you people could help with.
The game

1 6 sided dice.
2 actions: roll another time or stop.
if your next roll is >= your previous roll, your score adds up. Else you are busted and get 0 score.
If you stop or busted, it is the next players turn.
The winner is, who has a total score of 20 first.

Example of a players turn: rolls 1, action: roll, rolls 3, action: stop => Has earned 4 points (3+1) which is added to the players total score.
The Q-table
From the above game description I concluded that the table has 6 states/rows, one for each dice roll. And 2 actions (roll again or stop).
First question: Is that really correct? After all, if you have rolled 15 times a 1 already (a turn-score of 15), is the same strategy optimal, compared to you having just rolled a 1 once? Does your accrued round-score impact the strategy?
Second question: Which score-number would you use to do the updating of the q-table after a turn? The accrued round-score or just the value of an individual roll of the last dice? Should there not be a difference between a player just picking stop before rolling and a player rolling but busting? How would that be implemented within that RL algorithm-framework?
What did I do before posting this question?
In search for answers, before asking here, I did:

Read the wikipedia article
searched and found and skimmed over tons of blogs and articles (most of which explain nothing, but just use some python library)
watched some youtube CS class about reinforcement learning, but their hand picked examples never seem to match with whatever problem I try to solve.

So, a concise answer might not be only useful for me, but for anyone who really wants to be able to use that (class of) algorithms successfully.
Update
I will not bother you with tons of code, but I implemented the
21x21x21x6 with 2 actions, as well as the (rather useless) 6 with 2 actions versions.
The code is structured such, that the game state is represented by the tuple (opponent-score own-score turn-score last-roll), which can be transformed into an index in the observation axis of the q-table.
The 2 actions are :roll or :stop and a function choose-action, depending on *exploration-rate* either picks the action with the highest reward known so far or the other action if it is in exploring mood.
The function agent-match-round (agent1 agent2) is the driver, asking both agents for their actions according to the games rules.
Once an agent is done (:busted or :stop), it is the next agents turn. For each case (:busted or :stop or :roll), it calles the function game-step (agent arg) accordingly, which in turn updates the agents game state and updates the q-table according to the transition. A function agent-match sits on top of all that, orchestrating a full agent match to 20 points.
The q-table is a 2D array with the dimensions (64827 2). Even after hundreds of millions of such agent matches, about half of the q-table remains empty, which is either a bug or just because some states are rather unlikely. I expected it to be much less 'empty', though.
(compare-untrained-observations *a0* *a1*)
(:BOTH 31799 :ONLY-1 1306 :ONLY-2 2166)

I had the idea to merge the 2 agents to get a better fill grade, but as you see, the number of states, only one of both agents has data on is rather small.
I experimented with the hyper parameters, mostly with the *exploration-rate* in the range from 0.1 .. 0.5, but this did not have any noticeable impact on the fill-grade of the table.
This is how the "training loop" looks like:
(loop
   for i from 1 upto 10000000
   do (agent-match *a0* *a1*))

which needs a few minutes to complete. Even after running this a couple of times, the fill rate of the q-table only changes slowly. Maybe 1k new entries per training loop.
I still wonder about the reward function, I call game-score in my code.
(defmethod game-score ((game ddg-big))
  (let* ((state (drl-state game))
         (opp (property state :opp))
         (own (property state :own))
         (turn (property state :turn)))
    (cond
      ((and (> (+ own turn) opp) (>= (+ own turn) 20))
       25)
      ((and (< (+ own turn) opp) (>= opp 20))
       -25)
      (t
       (- (+ own turn) opp)))))

Particularly if it is a good idea, to also "punish" with negative rewards. It is a dice game after all and so, sometimes even right choices are "unlucky".

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

I expected an answer to point out, for example, that the 6x2 q-table will only reveal the obvious and will not be very useful for an agent to play the game well. And maybe someone would point out, that instead, for a game to 20 points, a 21x21x6 q-table would yield an actually well playing agent, or maybe even a 21x21x21x6 q-table (opponent score, own score, turn-score, last-roll). Questions about "hands on" about how to use an algorithm are by nature not the same as showing a bit of code and someone fixing a bug.

Good question and ideas. If the optimal strategy is not always "roll" then it should depend on at least the opponent's score: if they have 19 you should choose "roll", even if your last dice was "6". You might be able to get an exact mathematical solution, but if you are learning RL, then why not try to code and test all of the options?

As for the reward you can give +1/-1 only for the last action before winning/losing the game, or also try to construct some intermediate rewards.

More readable: +25 for a win -25 for a loss, (own new score - opponent score) otherwise.
